# Problems connecting to sql server

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010, winapp

I wrote an app in vs 2010, win 7, 32 bit sql server 2008. The sql server is on my local machine and i can connect just fine. The destination server and workstation for the app is 64 bit. The destination server is windows server 2012 r2 64 bit and i cannot install sql server 2008, so i installed sql express 2012. When i change the connection string in the app to point to the new server, i cannot connect and my app fails. Does anyone have any tips or suggestions on how to connect my app to the sql express instance? Or are my issues related to the 32 bit vs 64 bit differences?

Comment: can you connect with management studio from your local machine to the destination server?

Comment: Can you post the connection string you're trying to use? and indicate if the 2012 installation of express on the server was installed as the default instance? or SQLExpress instance (which is the default when installing express)

Comment: I am not able to connect to the destination server from my development machine / management studio on the dev machine. I don't have the connection string in front of me - but the install did not go to the default instance - it went to the SQLExpress instance. And the mdf I am trying to attach to in the connection string is "C:\SQLData\mw.mdf". Thanks for your help!!